# Platforms and 3rd Party Content

Tags: copyright

For me my **Website(A)** works as a Platform for Users to share Videos, Images and Links from Other Websites, Lets take for example **Youtube**

User(A)`of my Website` copied an Embed Code of Illegal Copyrighted Video Hosted on Youtube.

User(A) logged to my Website and used this Embed Code to show the Video.

so the steps are

```
Illegal 3rd-Party Embed Code Copyrighted (YT) Video 
-Uploaded By-> User(YT) 
-Taken By-> User(A) 
-Shared at-> Website(A).
```

Does my Website(A) takes any responsibiltiy of that 3rd-Party content?

I didn't host the Content or anything on my Website, It is hosted by Youtube, And Youtube allows me to take Embeded Codes of their Videos to share it on my Website.

Answer (score 1):

From a technical perspective, providing a link via the embedded code to copyrighted material hosted elsewhere means that your site isn't creating the illegal copy of the material.  Rather, YouTube is generating that illegal copy and serving it to the user's browser even though the code to retrieve the illegal copy came from you.  So, you wouldn't be the direct infringer but you could still be liable for contributory infringement, which requires you know of the infringing activity, and induce, cause or materially contribute to the infringing conduct of another.  Here, you providing the link would "materially contribute" to the infringing activity, so the issue would turn on your knowledge of whether the linked content was pirated or legitimate.

In any event, the DMCA safe harbor provision would protect you from liability as a "service provider" so long as you comply with the notice and take down requirements in the act and don't take a material role in selecting which materials are hosted on your site.  This is the same provision that protects YouTube from liability for hosting pirated content on their site.

Answer (score 0):

In the United States: Broadly, no, you aren't liable for hosting content you didn't make.  (see Section 230 of the Communications Decency Act).  There are probably some circumstances in ehich you might be exposed to liability, but I am not an expert on this.

Elsewhere, however, I do not know about your liability.